# Arranging of column in multiple excel files in R

Tags: r, csv

I am attempting to combine two or more columns in an automated way in some survey data (by using R). The data are in Excel file with `.csv` format. Example data:

Data frame name `Andy:`

```
Name : Andy
Country :
Location :
Time
 a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j    k    l    m    n    o
100  -2   100   1   159  200   5   250   5   100  -5   100  -6   2000
200   1   200   1   260  200   7   250   7   100  -7   200  -8   2500
300   0   300   1   480                                300       3000
          100   1
          200   1
          100   1
          200   1
          300   1
```

Data frame name `Benny:`

```
Name : Benny
Country :
Location :
Time
 a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j    k    l    m    n     o
100  -1   100   1   357  900   5   900   5   900  -5   900  -6   2000  -7
200   0   200   1   680  900   7   900   7   950  -7   950  -8   2500  -8
300   1   300   1   240                                970       3000  -9
          100   1   362
          200   1
          100   1
          200   1
          100   1
          200   1
          300   1
```

Desired result:

```
Andy   Andy   Benny   Benny
 a      b       a       b
100    -2      100     -1
200     1      200      0
300     0      300      1

Andy  Benny
 e      e
159    357
260    680
480    240 
       362

Andy  Andy  Andy  Andy  Andy  Benny  Benny  Benny  Benny  Benny  Benny
  j    k     l     m     n     j       k      l      m      n      o
 100  -5    100   -6    2000  900     -5     900    -6     2000   -7 
 100  -7    200   -8    2500  950     -7     950    -8     2500   -8
            300         3000                 970           3000   -9
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it correct that what you're looking for is simply to bind those columns together without any need that rows align in a certain way? Then the following should work:

```
# read data from csv file
Andy <- read.csv2("Andy.csv")
Benny <- read.csv2("Benny.csv")

# to bind two data frames together, they have to be of the same length, i.e. you need add two rows to Andy, even if they're only filled with NAs
Andy[(length(Andy$a)+1):length(Benny$a),] <- NA 

# bind columns together
df1 <- cbind(Andy[,c("a", "b")], Benny[, c("a", "b")])
df1 <- df1[complete.cases(df1),] # delete rows containing only NAs

# if you don't want to specify the column names directly, safe them in a vector first
colnam1 <- c("a", "b")
df1 <- cbind(Andy[,colnam1], Benny[, colnam1])
df1 <- df1[complete.cases(df1),]
```

I guess you would then have to change column names as well, as they are identical now. You can then do the same for all the three data frames you want to have. Is that what you want?

Data I'm using:

```
dput(Benny)
structure(list(a = c(100L, 200L, 300L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), b = c(-1L, 0L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c = c(100L, 
200L, 300L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 300L), d = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), e = c(357L, 680L, 240L, 
362L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), f = c(900L, 900L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), g = c(5L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), h = c(900L, 900L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), i = c(5L, 
7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), j = c(900L, 950L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), k = c(-5L, -7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), l = c(900L, 950L, 970L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), m = c(-6L, -8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), n = c(2000L, 
2500L, 3000L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), o = c(-7L, -8L, -9L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

dput(Andy)
structure(list(a = c(100L, 200L, 300L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), b = c(-2L, 
1L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 100L, 200L, 
100L, 200L, 300L), d = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), e = c(159L, 
260L, 480L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), f = c(200L, 200L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), g = c(5L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), h = c(250L, 
250L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), i = c(5L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), j = c(100L, 100L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), k = c(-5L, 
-7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), l = c(100L, 200L, 300L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), m = c(-6L, -8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), n = c(2000L, 
2500L, 3000L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), o = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Hi @EmLaskey. After I tried the command 

Andy[(length(Andy$a)+1):length(Benny$a),] <- NA , it didn't add two rows to Andy, instead, it made the first row of Andy become filled with Nas. Can you double check for me? And ya, I just want to simply bind those columns together without any need that rows align. Much Much appreciate

Comment: I double checked and the command still works for me & does what it's supposed to do. I will put my ````Andy````and ````Benny````as  ````dput()```` in case you want to check wether the data we used isn't identical. I don't know what else could be the problem.

Comment: I just realized - do you still have ````Name: Country:````etc. in your imported data frame? Then I would get rid of those first, this would indeed mess up row numbers and so on. If not and you don't need a generalized solution you can also just use ````Andy[9:10,] <- NA````.